# Triple Factorial

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I want to find an analytic function that satisfies $0!!! = 1$ and $n!!! = n (n-3)!!!$ and $n! = n!!! (n-1)!!! (n-2)!!!$.

The third criterion is somewhat similiar to gamma multiplication theorem, so I started from there, and I have found that:

$$ \prod \limits_{k=0}^{n} \Gamma(1+\frac{k}{n}) = (2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}} (n+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}-n} \Gamma(n+1)$$

From this I put this function platform $\gamma(n) = 3^{\frac{n}{3}} \Gamma(1+\frac{n}{3}) \frac{\sqrt{3}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{3}}} T(n) $, this function does satisfy the third criterion and also the second criterion, such that $T(n)$ is periodic function with period of $3$ to make the (2 and 3) criterion hold.

I used for $T(n) = a^{\cos(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})} b^{\sin(\frac{4 \pi n}{3})}$, and another time $T(n) = a^{\sin(\frac{2 \pi n}{3})} b^{\cos(\frac{4 \pi n}{3})} $ but when solving for $\gamma(1)=1 , \gamma(2)=2 , \gamma(3)=3$, I got 2 answers:

$$\gamma1(x) = \pi ^{\frac{1}{3} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}} \Gamma \left(\frac{x}{3}+1\right) 2^{\frac{\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} \cos
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}} 3^{\frac{x}{3}-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   x}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}} \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)}\right)^{\frac{\sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

$$\gamma2(x) = \Gamma \left(\frac{x}{3}+1\right) 2^{-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}}
   3^{\frac{x}{3}+\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  x}{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}} \pi ^{-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   x}{3}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  x}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   x}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}} $$

They both hold all criterion and so I want to find the relation between them so I let $ t(x) = \frac{\gamma1(x)}{\gamma2(x)}$ and I got this graph for $t(x)$:

[image]

My question is: if Factorial and Double Factorial are unique functions in the sense that they hold the similar to the above criterion and just they if we are looking in analytic function, do my 2 functions imply that Triple Factorial criterions are not unique?!

Comment: The factorial isn't the unique function satisfying $z!=z(z-1)!$ since one can multiply it by any $1$-periodic function. The corresponding non-uniqueness for the triple factorial is what you've shown here.